# Алгоритм проверки равенства перемножения

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, арифметика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм проверки следующего равенства

```
a[0]*a[1]*...*a[n-1] = b[0]*b[1]*...*b[m-1]
```

Количество операций должно быть не более O(n*m).

Каждый элемент массивов a и b типа long long, согласно алгоритму не должно быть переполнений типа.

Comment: Возможно, имеется в виду для каждого элемента одного массива и каждого элемента второго их сокращение на наибольший общий делитель?...

Comment: Или разложение на последовательность степеней простых множителей типа 2^12*3^7*41

Comment: Судя по сложности @Harry прав. Вас просят сократить все общие множители и убедиться что "и не осталось никого".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ставлю на GCD. При таких значениях (размер-то `long long`) факторизация работает просто ужасно. Тем более что при GCD есть микрооптимизация — первое же число, которое оказывается после прохода по элементам второго произведения, не равным 1, дает основания закончить проверку. В случае же факторизации надо раскладывать все числа.

Впрочем, может, я где-то что-то не так написал? Тогда перепроверьте и поправьте...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <numeric>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>

class muTimer
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    bool active = false;
    Clock::duration   duration_;
    Clock::time_point start_ = Clock::now(), stop_ = Clock::now();

    muTimer(const muTimer&)             = delete;
    muTimer& operator=(const muTimer&)  = delete;
public:
    using ns       = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using mks      = std::chrono::microseconds;
    using ms       = std::chrono::milliseconds;
    muTimer() { reset(); start(); }
    ~muTimer() = default;
    muTimer& reset()
    {
        duration_ = std::chrono::nanoseconds(0);
        active    = false;
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& start()
    {
        if (!active)
        {
            start_ = Clock::now();
            active = true;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    muTimer& stop()
    {
        if (active)
        {
            stop_      = Clock::now();
            duration_ += stop_ - start_;
            active     = false;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename T = mks>
        unsigned long long duration()
    {
        return static_cast<unsigned long long>
            (std::chrono::duration_cast<T>(stop_-start_).count());
    }
};


using namespace std;


default_random_engine rgen{random_device{}()};

// 1: definitery equals, 0: definitely different, -1: who knows?
int diff(const vector<long long>& a, const vector<long long>& b)
{
    int asign = 1, bsign = 1;
    for(auto n: a)
        if (n == 0) { asign = 0; break; }
        else if (n < 0) asign = -asign;
    for(auto n: b)
        if (n == 0) { bsign = 0; break; }
        else if (n < 0) bsign = -bsign;
    if (!asign && !bsign) return 1;
    if (asign * bsign == 1) return -1;
    return 0;
}



bool equalPrime(const vector<long long>& a, const vector<long long>& b)
{
    int d = diff(a,b);
    if (d == 0) return false;
    else if (d == 1) return 1;

    unordered_map<long long,int> z;
    for(auto n: a)
    {
        if (n < 0) n = -n;
        while(n%2 == 0) { z[2]++; n /= 2; }
        for (long long j = 3; j*j <= n; j += 2)
            while(n%j == 0) { z[j]++; n /= j; }
        if (n != 1) z[n]++;
    }
    for(auto n: b)
    {
        if (n < 0) n = -n;
        while(n%2 == 0) { z[2]--; n /= 2; }
        for (long long j = 3; j*j <= n; j += 2)
            while(n%j == 0) { z[j]--; n /= j; }
        if (n != 1) z[n]--;
    }
    for(auto x: z) if (x.second) return false;
    return true;
}

bool equalGCD(vector<long long> a, vector<long long> b)
{
    int d = diff(a,b);
    if (d == 0) return false;
    else if (d == 1) return 1;

    for(auto& i: a) if (i < 0) i = -i;
    for(auto& i: b) if (i < 0) i = -i;

    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < b.size(); ++j)
        {
            if (long long g = gcd(a[i],b[j]); g != 1)
            {
                a[i] /= g;
                b[j] /= g;
            }
        }
        if (a[i] != 1) return false;
    }
    for(auto i: a) if (i != 1) return false;
    for(auto i: b) if (i != 1) return false;
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    vector<long long> a, b;
    uniform_int_distribution  uint_d(0ll,200000000000000ll);

    for(int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
    {
        a.push_back(uint_d(rgen));
        b.push_back(uint_d(rgen));
    }

    bool p, q;
    {
        muTimer mt;
        q = equalGCD(a,b);
        mt.stop();
        cout << "equalGCD  : " << mt.duration<>() << " mks\n";
    }
    {
        muTimer mt;
        p = equalPrime(a,b);
        mt.stop();
        cout << "equalPrime: " << mt.duration<>() << " mks\n";
    }

    cout << p << q << endl;

}
```

Исправил с учетом замечаний Stanislav Volodarskiy. См. код [тут](https://gitlab.com/disputant/rustackoverflow/-/tree/master/exper/ProductsEquals) — генерация файла с простыми числами и проверка равенства произведений. Кому интересно, поиграйтесь.

Comment: Зависит от размера массивов. Если они очень длинные, то разложение по предварительно заготовленной таблице простых до 2^32 будет быстрее. Асимптотика.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Только вот сама табличка `int primes[]` занимает 813120888 байта (ее уже здесь считали). Ладно, попробую прикинуть с ней, без учета времени на ее составление или чтение...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Стало, понятно, полегче со временем (хотя таскать почти гигабайт в памяти удовольствие недешевое), но вот *при случайном наборе* чисел из-за высокого шанса оптимизации по первому отличному от нуля числу — чем длиннее массивы, тем хуже разница во времени. Т.е. тут как с быстрой сортировкой, грубо говоря: на плохих наборах, вероятно, за счет асимптотики выедет разложение на простые, но на среднем наборе обгонит GCD.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy В "плохом" случае, когда произведения равны (генерировал в первом произведении случайные числа в рамках `int`, во втором брал их попарные произведения), по крайней мере до 10000 членов в произведении GCD все равно быстрее.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ссылка на код в обновленном ответе в конце; можете нагенерировать разные варианты тестов и посмотреть, когда асимптотика обгонит... Для *совпадающих* произведений на 100000 (*небольших* :)) сомножителей наконец обогнала :) А вот для случайных до 2\*10^15 при 1000 сомножителей GCD обгоняет на 4 порядка

Comment: Случайный набор в данной задаче - не показатель. Даже если сравнить только степень двойки в произведениях, случайные наборы будут отсеяны за линейное время с вероятностью близкой к единице. Правда это потребует изменить порядок разложения чисел. В первый проход вычисляем степени двойки, во второй - тройки и т.п. Хорошие примеры - когда все простые множители (не сами числа) совпадают кроме может быть одной пары. Эти примеры трудны для разложения. Для НОД сложность мало зависит от чисел - появляется и пропадает логарифм - не существенно.

Comment: Вы меня заинтересовали задачей. Вообще постановка интересная: есть два алгоритма, каждый быстрее в одних обстоятельствах и медленнее в других. Как получить алгоритм объединяющий сильные стороны обоих. Я говорю не о параллельном исполнении, а о каком-то алгоритмическом решении.

Comment: Забавно, что на случайных наборах 4 порядка держатся и на 100000 сомножителей. Что до показательности... Ну так и для QuickSort случайный набор не показатель, вот отсортированный — дело другое... :) Вопрос в том, для чего *реально* это может использоваться. Например, все знают об алгоритмах Штрассена или Копперсмита-Винограда, только вот в реальности мне не повезло их ни разу встретить...

Comment: ... потому что они спрятаны на ваше счастье внутри библиотек линейной алгебры.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Кстати, это серьезная оптимизация! не раскручивать все степени, а идти поочередно, с проходами по каждому простому числу. Это сильный ход. А у меня еще возник вопрос, если два множества достаточно сильно разные по размеру, что лучше для GCD - какой цикл делать внутренним, а какой внешним?

Comment: Правило: внутренний цикл - самый длинный. Предсказателю переходов так легче работать. И кэшам процессора тоже.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я не с технической, а с алгоритмической точки зрения...

Comment: Не вижу разницы с алгоритмической точки зрения. Под любой порядок подбираются примеры где будет и медленно и быстро.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Оптимизация по отдельным простым числам отлично работает при случайных наборах (когда произведения не равны...), но вот на совпадающих получаем ужас, летящий на крыльях ночи... Что, в общем-то, логично. Все, на этом и остановлюсь, если не будет совсем уж сногсшибающих идей...

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Вдогонку по Копперсмиту-Винограду из Википедии: "*Этот алгоритм не представляет практического интереса в силу астрономически большой константы в оценке арифметической сложности.*" — так что сомневаюсь, что где-то в библиотеках за кулисами использовано в общем случае что-то, отличное от обычного простого перемножения.

Comment: @Harry Хорошо получилось + возможность досрочной остановки.  Но не закинуть альтернативу я не мог ;)

Comment: @MBo Да у меня к вам и вашему решению никаких претензий :) Просто задача заинтересовала — так часто бывает, вроде бы что-то и выеденного яйца не стоит, а копнуть рядом — и выкапываешь что-то интересное... (поворчу кстати: смотрю на нынешних студентов — поголовная болезнь отсутствием любознательности... Решают только от сих и до сих, а в сторону посмотреть — "это не задавали"...) Меня просто заинтересовало, ведь навскидку у каждого способа свои плюсы и минусы. Оказалось, и очень, очень сильная зависимость от данных.

Answer (score 2):

Кое-какие мысли по задаче.

### Ответ на вопрос

Так как запрошена сложность *O(nm)*, то вычисляем *НОД* для всех пар и сокращаем множители на эти *НОД*ы. Если остались все единицы, есть равенство. Алфавит конечный, считаем что *НОД* вычисляется за константу. Это решение уже привёл Harry. Ничего нового я не скажу.

### "Быстрый" алгоритм

Опять таки, алфавит конечный - значит разложение на простые делается за константу. Раскладываем все множители на простые, сравниваем степени при простых. Если равны все степени, то равны и произведения. Работает за линейное время - *O(n + m)*. Но константа тут неприятная.

Примем что, числа 64 бита со знаком. Максимальное значение *2<sup>63</sup>*. Для разложения потребуются простые до примерно трёх миллиардов (*√(2<sup>63</sup>)*). А именно *146144318* простых чисел. В худшем случае каждое число нужно будет делить 146 миллионов раз. Есть различные оптимизации, но есть и плохой случай, которые эти оптимизации не берут.

Наберём *2N* простых чисел не далеко от *√(2<sup>63</sup>)*. Превышать значение нельзя. Разобьем их на пары и составим из произведений в парах первый массив. Другое разбиение на пары того же набора чисел даст второй массив. Два разбиения можно так устроить, что равных чисел в массивах не будет. Это нужно чтобы не работала оптимизация "выкинем равные".

Чтобы разложить любое такое произведение требуется *146* миллионов делений.

На этом примере сравним квадратичный алгоритм и линейный. Сравнение на пальцах, но представление даёт. Самый дорогой *НОД* для наших чисел стоит *92* деления. Ещё два деления чтобы сократить общий множитель. Общее число делений для двух массивов из *n* чисел есть *94 n<sup>2</sup>*.

Линейный алгоритм потратит *146·10<sup>6</sup>·2n*. *2n* чисел, каждое надо разложить.

Приравняем их чтобы узнать при каком *n* линейный алгоритм начнёт обгонять квадратичный по числу делений (я уже говорил - оценка грубая). В районе трёх миллионов:

*94·n<sup>2</sup> = 146·10<sup>6</sup>·2·n*

*n ≈ 3.1·10<sup>6</sup>*

Тот случай, когда константу игнорировать нельзя. Я не вижу способа улучшить поведение линейного алгоритма в вышеприведённом "плохом случае". Отчасти это извиняет меня: я обещал поместить сюда ответ с линейным алгоритмом, но не буду. Но есть

### Надежда

Есть квадратичный алгоритм, не дождётесь ответа на длинных массивах. Есть линейный алгоритм, совершенно непрактичный (на специальных примерах, но всё же). Как можно решать задачу?

Если есть длинная арифметика с произведением за *n·log n* (*n* - количество цифр в множителях), то за *n·log<sup>2</sup>n* можно вычислить произведение *n* чисел фиксированной разрядности. Полученные произведения сравниваются как они есть. Требуемую арифметику на коленке не напишешь, но она есть в библиотеках доступных на всех популярных языках программирования.

Ещё один способ опирается на китайскую теорему об остатках. Берёте простое число и вычисляете произведения чисел в массивах по его модулю (несложно считается за линейное время). Если для двух массивов произведения по модулю различны, значит и обычные произведения различны. Если одинаковы, надо взять другой модуль. Повторять до тех пор пока произведение модулей не превысит любое возможное произведение чисел в массивах. Например *2n* больших модулей достаточно для массива длины *n*.

Это точный алгоритм, но опять таки квадратичный: каждый модуль проверяется за линейное время (за *O(n)*). Но и самих модулей тоже *O(n)*.

Не всё так плохо. Выберем большой случайный простой модуль *p<sub>1</sub>*, вычислим произведения по нему для двух массивов. Если они оба равны нулю, в массивах есть множители кратные модулю. Сократим их (с проверкой степени) и пересчитаем произведения. Какова вероятность что произведения по модулю равны, а нормальные произведения - нет? Она обратно пропорциональна *p<sub>1</sub>*. Если такой вероятности недостаточно, выберете другой случайный простой модуль *p<sub>2</sub>* (≠ *p<sub>1</sub>*). Если массивы прошли и этот тест, вероятность ошибки обратно пропорциональна *p<sub>1</sub>p<sub>2</sub>*. Повторяйте столько раз сколько вам нужно чтобы иметь практическую уверенность, что массивы действительно равны.

Последний алгоритм можно написать на коленке за пару вечеров. Нужен генератор больших случайных простых - это не сложно. Грубо говоря, генерируются большие случайные числа и проверяются на простоту вероятностным тестом (!).

Итого: есть детерминированный крайне сложный алгоритм за *n·log<sup>2</sup>n* и не очень сложный вероятностный алгоритм за *n*.

Answer (score 1):

Проходим каждый элемент массива `a` и с данным элементом проходим каждый элемент массива `b`. Вычисляем их НОД *(наибольший общий делитель)* и сокращаем оба элемента.
Но сначала вычисляем знак умножений и дальше работать будем только с положительными числами.
Умножения будут равны, если все числа останутся равными единице.

```
int знакA = знак ( a )
int знакB = знак ( b )

если знакA != знакB то
  return False

если знакA == 0 то
  return True

for ai из a do {
  for bi из b do {
    nod = НОД ( ai , bi )
    ai /= nod
    bi /= nod
    если ai == 1 то
      break
  }
  если ai != 1 то
    return False
}
return True
```

---

```
int знак ( a ) {
  зн = +1
  for ai из a do {
    если ai == 0 то 
      return 0
    если ai < 0 то {
      зн = - зн
      ai = - ai
    }
  }
  return зн
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Задачу можно решить за `O((m+n)*sqrt(maxvalue))` (множитель зависит от размера чисел, суть константа, но большая).

Каждое число раскладываем в произведение степеней простых множителей, складываем степени для всех чисел в списке, сравниваем наборы для двух списков. Демонстрация на Питоне.

Содержимое словаря после прохода первого списка:
`{1000000007: 1, 2: 10, 3: 5, 5: 2, 7: 1, 11: 1})`

```
from collections import defaultdict

def compareproducts(a, b):
    da = defaultdict(int)
    for F in a:
        d = 2
        while d*d <= F:
            m = 0   #степень множителя
            while F % d == 0:
                m += 1
                F //= d
            if m:
                da[d] = da[d] + m
            d += 2 if d > 2 else 1   #после двойки идём по нечётным
        if F > 1:
            da[F] = da[F] + 1
    for F in b:
        d = 2
        while d*d <= F:
            m = 0   
            while F % d == 0:
                m += 1
                F //= d
            if m:
                da[d] = da[d] - m
            d += 2 if d > 2 else 1   
        if F > 1:
            da[F] = da[F] - 1
    for v in da.values():  #все нули - произведения равны
        if v:
            return(False)
    return True

print(compareproducts([1000000007,479001600],[100000000700, 66528, 72]))

>> True
```

Comment: Вопрос только (как и у @AlexGlebe) — а какова сложность разложения на простые? (у него — поиск НОД).

Comment: Сложность разложения от log(maxvalue) до sqrt(maxvalue),  формально для longlong константа ;)

Comment: Я тут написал (на С++)  оба способа... При реально больших значениях (а сказано, что там long long...) проверка на простоту получается очень длинной, и GCD оказывается быстрее. Причем "быстрее" — это очень мягко сказано...

Comment: См. тестовый код в моем дополненном ответе.